# secret phase of mercurial commit pushed to remote in tortoisehg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I often make minor cosmetic re-formatting changes to code, which some people find only aesthetically pleasing and not worth doing and committing and pushing...

If I designate such local commits as `secret` and then push them to `remote`, will other developers be able to see these commits when they pull? Or will they only see the final code?

Comment: Once pushed, secret changes are no longer secret, they are changed to public.

Comment: I recommend you just create a test repository and try this stuff out. You will learn a lot that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the whole point of commits marked as secret, is that they **can't** be pushed to the server.

If you are going to make local changes, then I suspect you will have to keep rebasing the local only ones on top of your other work.